# Android Beginner: Emulator not running app or updating it

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, adt

```
[2012-02-14 11:57:59 - HarshaBoston] Android Launch!
[2012-02-14 11:57:59 - HarshaBoston] adb is running normally.
[2012-02-14 11:57:59 - HarshaBoston] Performing com.boston.harsha.startPoint activity launch
[2012-02-14 11:57:59 - HarshaBoston] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'Droid8'
[2012-02-14 11:57:59 - HarshaBoston] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'Droid8'
[2012-02-14 11:58:05 - Emulator] emulator: WARNING: Unable to create sensors port: Unknown error
```

Ok so this is what the console is showing. My emulator was working fine until a couple of days ago, then my projects were not updating the changes made to the main.xml file even though the changes were saved.

Now, I wanted to see if a new project would work, but no dice. The emulator runs fine, but my app is not loaded, I have no idea what to do to rectify this.

I'm using API Level 8, with ADT plugin Android SDK on eclipse on Windows XP.

Android beginner here. I was making a Hello World program, which ran fine a couple of days ago, but now nothing runs, and existing projects don't show the changes made to them. Please help! 
   Now when I run the emulator, the emulator runs fine but my app isn't even loaded!

I've already tried reinstalling the ADT, reinstalled the Android SDK,etc. nothing happpened

Also, the emulator doesn't seem to be showing up on the DDMS.

**FIXED IT!! SOLUTION FOR ANYONE FACING THIS PROBLEM**
 Apparently a lot of people in here seem to have this problem and only one of the threads had a good solution.

1. Firstly if this is happening to you, check the DDMS to see if the emulator is shown.    This is the a red flag. Apparently the adb server does not refresh or restart every time you restart eclipse.
2. Run the emulator. Chances are your app may not run on the emulator. Now, while the emulator is still running go the DDMS tab and next to the Screen Capture icon there is a dropdown menu with 'Reset ADB', click on it. Now your emulated device should be shown in the DDMS devices.
3. Run your app now. hopefully this solved your problem. Mine did!

Comment: Uninstall your app from emulator and again install it.

Comment: Keep the emulator running first. Then run your program/project. This should generally install your project on the already running emulator.

Comment: I did what you said. I ran the emulator first, then right-clicked on the project and ran the application, it just starts another instance of the emulator, without the app!

Comment: SOLVED! For the fix, check the edit on the opening post!

Comment: @harshalizee You should post an answer to your question and accept it. That way you show clearly to the SO community how you solved the problem

Comment: @Jose_GD Updated! Sorry about that. This was a year ago and I was not familiar with the way SO works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FIXED IT!! SOLUTION FOR ANYONE FACING THIS PROBLEM Apparently a lot of people in here seem to have this problem and only one of the threads had a good solution.

Firstly if this is happening to you, check the DDMS to see if the emulator is shown. This is the a red flag. Apparently the adb server does not refresh or restart every time you restart eclipse.

Run the emulator. Chances are your app may not run on the emulator. Now, while the emulator is still running go the DDMS tab and next to the Screen Capture icon there is a dropdown menu with 'Reset ADB', click on it. Now your emulated device should be shown in the DDMS devices.

Run your app now. hopefully this solved your problem. Mine did!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with developing my android app on an emulator. I would rebuild and install my application and it would keep installing an older version of my app (reinstalling app, and the answer above didn't help). Turns out running `ant clean` and rebuilding the project fixed it!